# Hololens 2 emulator not responding to user input

Tags: input, hololens, unreal-engine5, hololens-emulator

I'm trying to get an unreal project to run on my Hololens 2 emulator (version 10.0.20348.1543). I'm running this on a windows 11 pro machine.

I was able to install and launch the emulator without any issues. But when I run the emulator I get no response from any mouse clicks or keyboard clicks.

I've been digging around trying to find a solution. One common fix I see talks about disabling any proxy servers as that can interfere with the input, but I've gone through my settings and confirmed I don't have a proxy server running anywhere.

I've also seen people having issues with internet connectivity with their emulator and that effecting if inputs are read or not. I don't have an issue with internet connectivity with my emulator.

Past that I'm out of ideas. Hopefully someone can help me figure out why the emulator isn't responding to input.

I've tried rebooting my computer, uninstalling and reinstalling the emulator, I've tried different versions of the emulator. Nothing seems to work in fixing this issue.

Comment: Are you using any VPN? Please refer to the last case of Troubleshooting in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-hololens-emulator#troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm not using a VPN

Comment: Can check if running the emulator as administrator makes any difference?  Also, if still fails running emulator as admin (right click, run as administrator),  what is exact version of Win 11 OS that is showing failure?

Comment: I'm forced to run the emulator as admin, the emulator will say I don't have permissions and close if I don't run as admin.

Comment: I'm running Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on ‎2/‎23/‎2023
OS build 22621.1702
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22641.1000.0

Comment: @onewho Can update to latest Win11 22H2 release?  We cannot reproduce this here + should have the fix in it too that do not have to run as admin then too